# YUI DataTable in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, yui

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.  I am trying to populate my YUI data table with data from my database.

In my view I have the following code snippets:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.News>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/base/base-min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/button/assets/skins/sam/button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Assets/Stylesheets/MyProject.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/element/element-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/button/button-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datatable/datatable-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/datasource/datasource-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/connection/connection-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/json/json-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is how I create my data table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function () {
      var btnHelp, btnCreateNews;
      btnHelp = new YAHOO.widget.Button('btnHelp');
      btnCreateNews = new YAHOO.widget.Button('btnCreateNews');

      btnCreateNews.addListener('click', function (e) {
         window.location = '@Url.RouteUrl(Url.NewsCreate())';
      });

      var grdNewsColumnDefs = [
         { key: 'NewsId', label: 'Identifier' },
         { key: 'Title', label: 'Title' },
         { key: 'Body', label: 'Body' }
      ];

      var grdNewsDataSource = YAHOO.util.DataSource('@Url.Action("JsonList")');
      grdNewsDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
      grdNewsDataSource.responseSchema = {
         fields: [
            { key: 'NewsId' },
            { key: 'Title' },
            { key: 'Body' }
         ]
      };

      var grdNewsDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable('grdNews', grdNewsColumnDefs, grdNewsDataSource);
   });

</script>
```

My News class:

```
public class News
{
   public int NewsId { get; set; }

   public string Title { get; set; }

   public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

My action method:

```
public ActionResult JsonList()
{
   IEnumerable<News> newsList = newsService.FindAll();

   return Json(newsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The error that I get in the grid is:

**Data error.**

Not sure what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create a encapsulator class:

```
public class JsonEncapsulatorDto<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }

    public T DataSingle { get; set; }
}
```

in your action method use:

```
public ActionResult JsonList()
{
   var data = new JsonEncapsulatorDto<News>();
   data.Data = newsService.FindAll();

   return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now in your script:

```
var grdNewsDataSource = YAHOO.util.DataSource('@Url.Action("JsonList")');
      grdNewsDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
      grdNewsDataSource.responseSchema = {
         resultsList: 'Data',
         fields: [
            { key: 'NewsId' },
            { key: 'Title' },
            { key: 'Body' }
         ]
      };
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need encapsulator class like this?

Comment: You must define a resultsList in your reponse schema. So if you have all your result list at the root of the json response it will not work. Maybe you will need some pagination and the encapsulator class can be transformed into a pagination class.

Comment: Yes it works.  Thanks for the advice.  You have a property called DataSingle.  When and what is this used for?

Comment: it was for the case i had only one element to show in the json response you can delete it if you want.

Comment: Have you used YUI alot with MVC?  If so how do you find it with regards to ease of use and performance?