# sending json object from spring mvc controller to yui view

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, yui

I want to send a json object from spring mvc controller to a view since I have YUI data table and I want the json object to be the data source for this table. any advise or example close to this case will be appreciated :)

Comment: Check this [YUI DataTable in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5067102/461822), is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Jackson** converter and `@ResponseBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(...)  
public @ResponseBody Json getJson(){ 
    return new Json();
}
```

Follow these [instructions](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/03/28/spring-mvc-tip-returning-json-from-a-spring-controller/).

Comment: I am not using maven , I tried this but I am still getting data error in the view , it seems like the view can't read the json object

Comment: sai ,Thank you for your reply , no I think I have a problem with configrations in the spring xml file.

Comment: Yes don't forget to add 'MappingJacksonJsonView' in your Spring config.

Comment: Benoit , I am getting error during running , no class def found for org/codehaus/jackson/map/objectmapper

Comment: You need to add the jar using maven or by downloading it : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload

Comment: I tried to run my project on netbeans using glass fish , it works fine without any configuration on the spring configuration file , but when I tried to use tom cat , I got the same problem.